# How to determine the fractal dimension of a random walk in 2D?

Tags: mathematical-physics, random-walk, computational-mathematics, fractals, fractal-analysis

I have to determine the fractal dimension of a random walk in 2D. How can I do that?
I am first supposed to picture the random walk for 2D as in the following [site](https://towardsdatascience.com/random-walks-with-python-8420981bc4bc). However, I am also asked to calculate the fractal dimension of it. How can I do that? What I only know, is:
$$N = \epsilon^{-D}$$
where D is the number of dimensions, $\epsilon$ the scaling factor, and N the number of sticks of length $\epsilon^{-1}$needed to measure a line.
After that, I am given the following formula for determining the fractal dimension:
$$D = \lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{\log{[N(\epsilon_i)/N(\epsilon_{i+1})]}}{\log{[\epsilon_{i+1}/\epsilon_i]}}}$$

How can I use this definition for my random walk?

Thanks!

Comment: To progress, you need the precise definition of Fractal dimension that you want to compute.

Comment: I added the formula I was given to calculate the dimension.